# Why when you sign up for bitcoins they do all the security questions of your identity but then you cannot use none of them to recover wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery

Why you cannot recover your praise with face recognition

Answer (score 2):

The Bitcoin network is a decentralized network of computers located all around the world. There is no central authority with which your identity is registered when you own some amount of bitcoin, so there is no mechanism to 'recover a wallet with facial recognition', or anything else like that. You simply will have the private keys that allow you to spend your coins, or not.

That said, there are many businesses and services that exist around the world, that work to provide users with bitcoin-related services (such as facilitating buying/selling of coins, storage service, payment processing, etc). Some of those services may require you to give up your personal information in order to become a customer, but in that case your information is not transmitted to the bitcoin network itself, it is just held by the company (and anyone they share it with, or lose it to).

So it may be possible to recover your account with such a business by way of your KYC/personal information, it will just depend on the services offered by said business. But when you are the custodian of your own coins/keys, **it is your responsibility to make the appropriate backups and keep them safe**.

Answer (score -2):

Naomi I understand the frustration but Bitcoin is a decentralized method of payment with lesser influence of the wallet organization. Wallets like coinbase and coinmama make it almost impossible to loose your coin. Setting up account on those platform provide you a great way of recovering your coin and not just limiting you to the 12phrase word

Comment: re: *"Wallets like coinbase and coinmama make it almost impossible to loose your coin"*: that isn't really true, there is a long history of custodial services losing customer funds due to hacks or mismanagement.